# latex on ubuntu can't find source file

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to compile a tex file on ubuntu 14.04 but I get a very strange error.

When I do:

```
"latex nextwim.tex"
```

I get:

> "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
>    restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   ! I can't find file `nextwim.tex'.
>   <*> nextwim.tex
>
> (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
>   Please type another input file name:"

I am in the same directory as the file:

```
"ls -lh nextwim.tex"
```

gives

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 timothy timothy 35K aug. 19 16:37 nextwim.tex

Maybe on ubuntu I need to set some variable to "." to let latex search the current directory?

Comment: Try to see what `latex` means for your system, maybe it points to a shell script or something wrong. Type `which latex` at the command prompt in the folder where `nextwim.tex` is and follow the returned link to inspect. Try `pdflatex nextwim` (or xelatex, lualatex) just to see if those engines can see the file in the current folder. Also try  `cat  nextwim.tex` -- this should list the file on the screen if it's in the current folder.

Comment: Try a command `kpsewhich -progname=latex -var-value TEXINPUTS`
to see if a period for the current directory is printed or not.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: thanks for the idea - it seems that TEXINPUTS was empty, and adding
`TEXINPUTS=.:$TEXINPUTS`
to my .bashrc file fixed the problem